# R : how to get all the months from the dataset, instead of 1 month a time

Tags: r, dataset

With this code, you get all the crimes in Nottingham in March for instance. You are required to enter a year and month, in this example March 2020. But I need all the months of the year 2020. How can I achieve this?

```
data <- as.data.frame(ukc_crime_location(lat = 52.959021, lng = -1.154041, date = "2020-04"))
```

Comment: Try `date=format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),length.out = 12,by = '1 month'),'%Y-%m')`

Comment: `ukc_crime_location` is not a base R package, please post in what package can it be found.